# sqlcmd.exe -v will not parse an empty string parameter

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm trying to pass some parameters to sqlcmd.exe using the -v switch. Everything works fine as long as none of the parameter values are empty strings. When I try to pass an empty string, it seems that sqlcmd.exe gets confused. For example:

```
sqlcmd.exe -S myserver -v myvar1 = "value1" myvar2 = "" -i "myscript.sql"
```

Produces the error message:

```
"Sqlcmd: '= value1': Invalid argument
```

Anyone know how to circumvent this bug?

Comment: Try the value with a single space instead of an empty string: `myvar2 = " "`? In SQL statements on SQL Server, comparing varchars ignores trailing spaces; it might work.